# Follow up of the post: "...why are there no “justify-items” and “justify-self” properties?"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Follow up question of: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties)

Would someone be so kind as to help me combine boxes 55 & 56 [from the top answer]?

This is what I'm looking for [image]

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered">
    55
  </div>
  <div class="bottomright">
    56
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been struggling with it all day and I give up! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Would you be able to add a code snippet to help us solving your issue?

Comment: and change the title, so that it accurately reflects your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to accomplish that, where i.e. the *56* could be positioned absolute, though here I decided to use a pseudo to match it, so it will be more responsive.

What make this work is that the pseudo match the height of the *56*, hence the *55* will be centered in the middle of its parent.

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;           /*  flow vertically  */
  justify-content: space-between;   /*  create a gap between items  */
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.container .centered {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
  background: lime;
}

.container .bottomright {
  width: 20%;
  background: lime;
  align-self: flex-end;             /*  align right  */
}

.container::before,
.container .bottomright {
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
}

/* extra styling, make text centered  */
.container .centered,
.container .bottomright {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered">
    55
  </div>
  <div class="bottomright">
    56
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can achieve this with margins as well, to avoid setting a height on the `container`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;           /*  flow vertically  */
  align-items: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.container .centered {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 30px 0;                   /*  top/bottom margin  */
  background: lime;
}

.container .bottomright {
  width: 20%;
  background: lime;
  align-self: flex-end;             /*  align right  */
}

.container::before,
.container .bottomright {
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
}

/* extra styling, make text centered  */
.container .centered,
.container .bottomright {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered">
    55
  </div>
  <div class="bottomright">
    56
  </div>
</div>
```